# how to get certain line from file using python

Tags: python

I need to get a certain part of my file and write it in new file. Keep the rest in a new file. So I will have 3 files . 1) Original file 2)Selected lines 3) The rest . I have a code that works for taking the first selection. I'm having  problem to get the next selection and so on. Here's my code :

```
counter=0
with open('1','r') as file1: #open raw data
    with open('2','w') as file3:
        with open('3','w') as file_out: 
            for i in file1: 
                if counter <10: ############# Next I need to get line 10 to 20 followed by 20 to 30
                    file_out.write(i)
                else:
                     file3.write(i) 
                counter += 1
```

How can I change my code so that I can get the next selection?

Comment: So you are trying to strip the first 30 lines, create a new file with them, and keep what's left of the old file separately?

Comment: yes. so the files that have leftovers will be different from each other . For example, take the first 10 line from file A, call it B, keep the rest in file C . Next, take 10 to 20 lines, from file A, call it D, keep the rest in E.

Comment: And you need to do this exactly 3 times, or it will vary?

Comment: It will vary . I'm trying to create files for 10 fold cross validation. I'm new to python so I'm thinking to do the 10 separately so that I understand what's going on. By separately I mean, repeat the process manually but just change the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this make what you want?

```
def split_on_crosses(infile, chunk_size):
    head_num = 1  # counter for chunks
    head_file = open('1-head.txt', 'w')  # outport to first head file
    tails = []  # outports to tail files
    with open(infile,'r') as inport:  #open raw data
        for i, line in enumerate(inport, start=1):
            head_file.write(line)
            for t in tails:  # write to all tail files
                t.write(line)
            if i % chunk_size == 0:  # boundary of chunk is reached
                tails.append(open('%s-tail.txt' % head_num, 'w'))  # add one tail file
                head_num += 1
                head_file = open('%s-head.txt' % head_num, 'w')  # switch to next head file

split_on_crosses('infile.txt', 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For speed, I will assume the file is small enough to hold in memory (rather than re-reading the file each time):

```
from itertools import islice

BLOCKSZ = 10      # lines per chunk

# file names
INPUT = "raw_data.txt"
OUTPUT_LINES  = lambda a, b: "data_lines_{}_to_{}.txt" .format(a, b-1)
OUTPUT_EXCEPT = lambda a, b: "data_except_{}_to_{}.txt".format(a, b-1)

def main():
    # read file as list of lines
    with open(INPUT) as inf:
        data = list(inf)

    num_blocks = (len(data) + BLOCKSZ - 1) // BLOCKSZ
    for block in range(num_blocks):
        # calculate start and end lines for this chunk
        start =  block      * BLOCKSZ
        end   = (block + 1) * BLOCKSZ

        # write out [start:end]
        with open(OUTPUT_RANGE(start, end), "w") as outf:
            for line in islice(data, start, end):
                outf.write(line)

        # write out [:start] + [end:]
        with open(OUTPUT_EXCEPT(start, end), "w") as outf:
            for line in islice(data, start):
                outf.write(line)
            for line in islice(data, end - start):
                pass
            for line in inf:
                outf.write(line)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit:** I just realized I made a mistake in my line-slicing for OUTPUT_EXCEPT (thinking of islice offsets as absolute not relative); this is now fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . However, I prefer a simpler method that I can use to change my code for example change the counter part where I can take a range rather than just counter >10 , I need some thing like counter == [10:20] .. I have another code to do some calculation for output files below this code, and if I change too much of the top part, I will have trouble in changing the calculation part. As python is very new to me, it took sometime for me to create the calculation part so I would be happy if i could just simply change somewhere near the counter part. I appreciate your answer .

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, written in Python3.x.

```
#read file1, get the lines as an array, length of said array, and close it.
alpha=open('alpha.txt','r')
alphaLine=alpha.readlines()
alphaLength=len(alphaLine)
alpha.close()

#lines above 10 and below 20 are sent to beta, while 10 to 20 are sent to gamma.
beta=open('beta.txt','w')
gamma=open('gamma.txt','w')
for i in range(alphaLength):
    if i<9:
        beta.write(alphaLine[i])
    elif i<20:
        gamma.write(alphaLine[i])
    else:
        beta.write(alphaLine[i])
beta.close()
gamma.close()
```

Comment: how is this different from my code above ? I can get the first line perfectly . I need to get the next range i.e lines 10 to 20 from raw data. This is the part where I can't compute.